# Does Facebook offer a callback URL for a change in scope?

Tags: facebook, permissions, callback

I understand that there's a [callback URL for when someone removes an app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#deauth-callback), but is there a callback for when someone changes the scope (permissions) for your app?

In particular, I'm wanting to get a callback if the user removes the "publish_actions" permission, which enables the app to post on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such callback functionality. You should always be 'skeptical' about the permissions granted to your app, since they can indeed be revoked.

The following documentation explains how you should handle the permissions and check for permissions before performing the API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#handling

Since you should only post to the wall (using publish_actions), you can check at that exact moment if the permission is available, or handle the error exception in a correct way.